# How to copy multiple files according a txt file in python

Tags: python, copy, shutil, os.walk

Please help me.
I'm trying to move files from one directory to another according to a list. 
The text file(mp3text.txt)looks like this:
p008-002031903
p008-002031906
p008-002031910
Each line contains a file name without a path. The other directory(e:\p008) contains hundreds of files(p008-002031910.spx).
I had tried many times.it could run part of it but couldn't copy anything. Many Thanks!

```
import os
import shutil

destination = 'e:\\result'

with open('c:\\mp3text.txt', 'r',encoding= 'utf-8') as lines:
    filenames_to_copy = set(line.rstrip() for line in lines)
for root, _,filenames in os.walk('e:\\p008'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename in filenames_to_copy:
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, filename), destination)
```

Comment: I had also tried Linux. There's an error:(find: missing argument to '-name').
#!/bin/bash
cat ./mp3text.txt | while read line
do
    echo $line
    find ./p008 -name $line | xargs -i cp -rf {} ./result/
done

Answer (score 0):

```
<mp3text.txt xargs -I filename find ./p008 -name filename | xargs -I filepath cp -rf filepath ./result/
```

Without having the filesystem examples to hand it's hard to say if this will 100% work though.

Comment: Thanks. I  had tried your method. but it didn't work either. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I had figured it out finally! 
The script is no problem. 
The problem is the File extension from the source directory. 
After I deleted the file extension. 
It works!